# How to fill timepicker field with capybara

Tags: xpath, capybara, contains, timepicker

I am new to capybara and I have some problems with text field, Capybara can not find the field.

I need to create automatic tests and one of them has to fill in fields that changes all the time(id and name changes, they are like this: id="patternDailyStart_146d7547140" and this number is always different).

#### Html part looks like this:

```
    <div class="timepicker">
    <input value="" id="patternDailyStart_146d7547140" 
        name="patternDailyStart_146d7547140" 
        class="timepicker-input patternDailyStart hasDatepicker" 
        type="text">
    <img class="ui-datepicker-trigger"      
        src="/mpromoter/assets/4716a6a0a357181/app/components/timefield/clock.png" 
        alt="..." 
        title="...">
    </div>
```

This is time picking field. And The problem is that capybara can not find the field.. however I try to find it for filling.

When I try to find this xpath, then it is found, but when I want to fill it in with time($starttime=17:00) then it says that element not found or it does not exist.

#### These xpaths are found:

```
page.has_xpath?('//tbody/tr/div/input[contains(., "patternDailyStart")]')
page.has_xpath?(:xpath, "//*[@class='timepicker-input patternDailyStart hasDatepicker']")
```

#### I tried to fill in like this:

```
And(/^fill up the fields$/) do
field = find("//*[@class='timepicker-input patternDailyStart hasDatepicker'")
field.set $starttime
end
```

#### And like this:

```
fill_in('timepicker-input.patternDailyStart.hasDatepicker', :with => $starttime)
```

#### And like this:

```
within(:xpath,'//tbody/tr/div/input[contains(., "patternDailyStart")]'){ fill_in("#patternDailyStart", with: $starttime)}
```

And many other ways but still nothing fills in those fields..

So I am asking for some help. What I have to do, any suggestions?

Thank you... :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest would be to locate the inputs by its 'patternDailyStart' class:

```
find(:css, '.patternDailyStart').set($starttime)
```